# Spring batch how to let the Writer know that it received the last entity running through the flow

Tags: spring-batch

I have a flow of Reader -> Processor -> writer

Every 50 Million records the writer is writing the data into a file and zip it.

the problem is that once the Reader has finished the Writer still "holds" many records which are not written since it didn't reach the 50 M records threshold.

Any advise on how to implement it in a way that the data will be written to many files with 50 M records each and a single file with the renaming records ?

Comment: How are you currently limiting the threshold to 50M? Couldn't you use chunks of that size in order to achieve what you want?

Comment: Currently i'm counting the number of rows that the writer receives from the processor and flush every 50M, the problem is that the data doesn't feet excatly to these chunk size, for example an input of 201M will produce 4 files of 50 M but 1 M records will not be written anywhere.

Comment: Are you setting the chunk size to 50M? According to your example, the last 1M records will be written in a fifth file. I suggest that you share a code sample of what you are trying to achieve with just a few records to be able to help you (For example, 5 input records with a chunk size of 2 should yield 3 output files).

Comment: Yes, 4 files of 50M each and 1M not written. Flush only occurs when the threshold is reached, otherwise the 1M records are not flush and the program ends without writing. I'm looking for a way to use the BatchJobCompletionListner or some other context entity in order to let the writer know that there are no more entities coming down the flow and that the 1M should be flushed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `MulitResoureceItemWriter`, you can use chunk size to dictate how this should work.  It can be configured to write at your specific threshold and if there is a remainder in the final chunk, that will also be written out.  You can read more about this useful delegate in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemWriter.html

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not using MulitResoureceItemWriter, and using it will probably requires changes to my writer, any other solution ?